# Prolog -- better way to eliminate duplicate answer in special case?

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

I was having trouble with these two lines:

```
list_swizzle(L, [], L).
list_swizzle([], L, L).
```

The problem was that if the both of the first two arguments are the empty list, the first two statements would both be used, returning the same answer. However, if I put a cut in one, it wrecks backtracking. I eventually put in this line above them:

```
list_swizzle([], [], []):- !.
```

And it works. But I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: This cut is again a red cut. You can see this for: `list_swizzle(Xs,Ys,Zs), Xs = [_]` which fails with above cut. It succeeds with an answer as given by @daf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my version:

```
list_swizzle([H|T], [], [H|T]).
list_swizzle([], L, L).
```

I'm counting on [] not unifying against [H|T] in the first fact. In other words [] has no T because it's the empty list so the first fact doesn't match goals with a [] in the first arg.

I've run this successfully on SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 32 bits, Version 5.8.2)

```
$ cat tt.pl

s([H|T], [], [H|T]).
s([], L, L).
```

....

```
For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- [tt].
% tt compiled 0.00 sec, 920 bytes
true.

?- s(L,[],[]).
L = [].

?- 
% halt
```